# Remove Firebase dependencies on iOS in React Native 0.61

Tags: firebase, react-native, cocoapods

I have read a lot of articles similar my title. But they are not working for me.
I am working on React Native iOS project and need to delete firebase dependencies from iOS project.
[image]

So I have removed firebase core import line in ios/Podfile and then pod clean and pod install. But it is not working for me.
Firebase is installed so on. Please help me with correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the line from the Podfile
- `pod deintegrate`
- `pod install`

Comment: Are you sure this is right? I have done with your method but it isn't helpful.

Comment: What Firebase dependencies are left after you do that?

Comment: All of firebase dependencies.

Comment: The Podfile.lock should show why dependencies are added to the Xcode project.

Comment: how about delete Podfile.lock?

Answer (score 0):

Go through with these steps:

1.Remove the line pod/firebase from your pod file

2.run command npm uninstall react-native-firebase in your project root folder

3.Run pod install in ios folder.