# How to remove react-native firebase dependency

Tags: firebase, react-native, cocoapods, uninstallation

How i can remove firebase from my project entirely, though i have tried all commands that i could find, but after all attempts again it appears in podfile.lock and still in project

```
react-native unlink react-native-firebase

npm unlink react-native-firebase

react-native unlink react-native-firebase

react-native uninstall react-native-firebase
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

> npm uninstall react-native-firebase

Comment: look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63985661/remove-firebase-dependencies-on-ios-in-react-native-0-61)